# Solutions of this system of PDE's

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations, differential-calculus

This question is related to the existence of Einstein metrics on tangent bundles where the metric is induced by the [isotropic almost complex structures](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02568316) on the tangent bundle. I'm trying this on the hyperbolic space and I got the following equations as the necessary  conditions for the existence of such metrics on  $T\mathbb{H}^2$. We consider $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ is  coordinate system on $T\mathbb{H}^2$ and $\alpha =\alpha (x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ is a positive function and $\rho$ is an arbitrary constant.
$$ y_1\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_2}-y_2 \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_1}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_1}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_2}+\frac{1}{x_2}(y_1\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_1}+y_2\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_2})=0,$$
$$ \frac{x_2^2}{2\alpha}\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_1}\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_2}+x_2^2 \frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{\partial y_2 \partial y_1} + \frac{1}{2\alpha ^3}\frac{y_1y_2}{x_2^2}=0 ,$$
$$ \rho =-\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{x_2^2}{2}(\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{\partial y_2^2 } +\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{\partial y_1^2})-\frac{1}{2\alpha ^3}\frac{y_1^2+y_2^2}{x_2^2},$$
$$ \rho=-\frac{x_2^2}{2}(\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{\partial y_2^2}-\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{\partial y_1^2})-\frac{x_2^2}{2 \alpha}(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_2})^2+\frac{1}{2\alpha ^3}\frac{y_1^2}{x_2^2} ,$$
$$ \rho=-\frac{x_2^2}{2}(\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{\partial y_1^2}-\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{\partial y_2^2})-\frac{x_2^2}{2 \alpha}(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y_1})^2+\frac{1}{2\alpha ^3}\frac{y_2^2}{x_2^2} .$$

Where $x_2\neq 0$ and we need to find $\alpha$ and we need $\alpha$ to be positive even locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem can be simplified considerably if you use the fact that the first equation and the second equation imply that $\alpha$ has the form $\alpha = f(x_2,r)$ where $r = {y_1}^2+{y_2}^2$.  Then the third equation implies that, in fact, $\alpha$ must have the form 
$$\alpha(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) = g\left(\frac{r}{{x_2}^2}\right) =  g\left(\frac{{y_1}^2+{y_2}^2}{{x_2}^2}\right)$$ 
for some function $g$ of a single variable.

Now, the remaining equations (which are second order) will give you a set of ODE for $g$, and you should easily be able to tell whether they have solutions.